# Please recommend wpf/silverlight control suit

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

I am developing an application which will have a WPF interface and a Silverlight/Azure implementation

So I'm looking to invest in a control suit that will require as little repeat work for the two UI implementations.  The DataGrid must be top-notch as well as integration with an MVVM development model.  Also important - reporting in various formats such as excel and pdf.

Support quality an active user community are important obviously.

All inputs and comments are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having used several different control suites across multiple platforms, I would happily recommend [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) as it is the one we keep coming back to.

They have a massive online community and support is very good. A key factor for us was availability of source code as we often develop app for clients requiring full access to all source.

Comment: Have you had experience with parallel development for Silverlight and WPF?

Comment: Yes, We have created projects for both and shared much code between them. All our projects use Telerik RadControls unless a client already has another product.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend DevExpress based on experience with their support team, even their CTO replies to questions sometimes.

Comment: Seconded. However, their WPF controls do not fully support data binding and as a result an MVVM implementation can sometimes can a little unsatisfying. They are working on improving this, though.

Comment: The lack of source code from DevExpress has been a problem for us. Support query responses are often along the lines of "no, we do not intend to support that"

Comment: Have you had experience with parallel development for Silverlight and WPF?